# パッケージimportができない: ImportError: cannot import name 'UnExpectedError'

Tags: python, python3

初めまして現在パッケージimportの書き方について悩んでおります。
`__init__.py`の書き方が悪いのか
`cmd.py` から `errors.py`　のエラークラスを呼んでくる事が出来ません

ネットにて調べてみたのですがどうしても分からず質問させて頂きます
どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃればご教授下さい

main.py

```
from Utilities.output import Logs
```

Utilities.__init__.py

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from Utilities import errors
from Utilities import cmd
from Utilities import output
from Utilities import outs


from Utilities.errors import BaseError
from Utilities.errors import UnusableError
from Utilities.errors import UnExpectedError

from Utilities.errors import InputError
from Utilities.errors import StatusError

from Utilities.output import Logs

from Utilities.cmd import Command

from Utilities.outs import trading
from Utilities.outs import initialize
```

errors.py

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from Utilities.output import Logs

log = Logs()

# 全ての基本となるエラー
class BaseError(Exception):
    def __init__(self,message):
        log.Error(message)

# 使用出来ないエラー
class UnusableError(BaseError): pass

# 予期せぬエラー
class UnExpectedError(BaseError): pass

# 入力形式エラー
class InputError(BaseError): pass
以下省略
```

TrackBack

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\user\dev\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Utilities.output import Logs
  File "c:\user\dev\Utilities\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Utilities import errors
  File "c:\user\dev\Utilities\errors.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Utilities.output import Logs
  File "c:\user\dev\Utilities\output.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Utilities.cmd import Command
  File "c:\user\dev\Utilities\cmd.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Utilities.errors import UnExpectedError,InputError
ImportError: cannot import name 'UnExpectedError'
```

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 2):

とりあえず __init__.py は今回はあまり関係なくて、errors, output, cmdの3つのモジュールが循環参照して三つ巴状態になっているのが原因です。

- errors: outputに依存(output.Logsを使用)
- output: cmdに依存(エラーメッセージからcmd.Commandを使用)
- cmd: errorsに依存(エラーメッセージからerrors.UnExpectedErrorを使用)

[image: インポートの依存関係の図]

cmdがerrorsをimportしようとした時にはまだerrorsのimportが完了していない状態であるため、UnExpectedErrorが参照できません。

解決するには、この三つ巴の循環参照をどこかで断ち切らなければなりません。
例えばoutput.pyでcmd.Commandを使うのをやめればimportはできるようになります。
（モジュールをどう設計すればよいかの話になります）

Comment: 分かりやすくありがとうございます！
循環がダメとは全く知りませんでした。
設計を組み直します

Answer (score 0):

Pythonのマニュアルには「パッケージ」のことは殆ど何も書いてないので難しく考えない方がいいようです。

`__init__.py`は、このファイルがあるディレクトリーをパッケージとして扱うので作る必要はありますが、中身は空でも構いません。一般的には、パッケージを初期化するためのコードを書きます。今回は、とりあえずは空のファイルでいいでしょう。

`cmd.py`から`errors.py`のエラークラスを呼ぶのは次のように普通に`improt`文を書けば呼べます。

```
from Utilities.errors import BaseError, UnusableError, UnExpectedError

class Command:
    def test():
        # 処理
        BaseError('message')
        # 処理
        UnusableError('massage')
        # 処理
```